# como enviar dados para outra pagina em html

Tags: php, javascript, html, formulário

eu tenho um formulario em que o usuario vai preencher com os dados e irá voltar para a pagina inicial do site, e uma tela de login do adm em que ele ira logar e ira ver uma pagina com os dados que os usuarios preencheram, como faço isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

agora quero direcionar o usuario ao index.html e o ADMform a essa pagina recebendo os dados que o php ta imprimindo

Comment: Coloca esse trecho de codigo na pergunta, fica mais fácil de compreender

Answer (score 0):

Sua pergunta está confusa, mas se entendi bem, você quer ter acesso à informações de todos os usuários que preencheram estas informações. Se for isso, você precisa de um banco de dados para armazenar estes dados e poder consulta-los depois. 
Um exemplo com MySQL seria:

```
$server = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "nomeDoBanco";

//Criar a conexao
$con = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password, $dbname);
```

Depois disso, você precisa de uma query para cadastrar infos:

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO nomeTabela (campos) VALUES $info1, $info2..." ):
```

E para exibir todas para o administrador:

```
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM nomeTabela");
```

Caso não seja isso que você quer, explique melhor a sua dúvida. Se não faz ideia do que estou falando, pesquise um pouco sobre Banco de Dados.

Obs. para direcionamento de páginas você pode usar:

```
echo "<script> location.href='../páginaQualquer.php'; </script>";
```